# OSX App doesn't start(Buid succeeded)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode8, macos-sierra

**Problem: I am unable to launch my OSX app.**

**Software versions:**

- XCode Version 8.1 (8B62)
- macOS Siera 10.12.1 (16B2657)

**I've already tried:**

- I don't have any changes in my version control.
- Also it works fine on my colleague's computer
- I've already tried to clean, Also used deep clean
- I've overloaded my mac twice
- I've already removed derived data

But still unable to run OSX app. It just build successfully all the time and isn't going to launch my app.

I googled about it.

https://www.google.com/search?q=xcode+%22build+secceded%22&oq=xcode+%22build+secceded%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.12138j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=xcode+%22build+succeeded%22+%22App+doesn%27t+run%22

But haven't found something helpful.

Any suggestions? Probably I missed something... but I think it is a system bug. And I have to clean or relaunch something. But I've already tried all what I was able to guess.

**Information from console**:

- /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-awtljghmrbqhgebrvruwulpmysqx/Build/Products/Debug/App Name.app/Contents/MacOS/App Name signature not valid: -67030
- proc 1042: load code signature error 4 for file "App Name"
- AMFI: allowing exception handler for 'App Name' (2504) because the process is unsigned.
- Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
- error: Attach failed: "No such process".
- error: attach failed.
- 1 +0.000000 sec [09c9/1503]: error: ::read ( 3, 0x700009325a40, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
- Exiting.

**PS
Any way. thanks for attention.**

Comment: what kinda app is yours? cocoa? command line tool?

Comment: When you run, you say build succeeds, but what does it say about running?

i.e, if running succeeds, Xcode will say: Running AppName: AppName

Comment: Also, check the Console application to see if it's logging anything suspicious about your launch.

Comment: Cocoa app... Nothing in XCode command line, I'll try Console application. Thanks for idea.